# How to have a line chart that responds to a slicer?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Table which I have has month-wise counts from July,2018. Data goes untill December 2020.

I have a slicer which selects the month and the year for the other visuals on the page.

I need to create a line chart which dynamically shows last 2 years of data or 24 months of data. So say suppose if I select, November 2020 from slicers, I need to see a graph that starts from November 2018 and ends at November[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ8P0.png) 2020. I need to have a text - "Current year" and "Previous Year" in the legend which is also another challenge that I am facing.

Below is the image for reference.

Please help me write the correct DAX

Comment: You need to write a measure that will filter dates for the desired period. Have a look at CALCULATE, DATESBETWEEN ans SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR. you may also want to look at calculation groups, which will make it easy to put current vs previous year in the legend.

Comment: And also, as is the custom at stackoverflow, please show what is your approach, what have you tried so far and where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe DAX is not the only option. You could try using a filter with 'relative date'.
[Microsoft documentation relative date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-slicer-filter-date-range)